# Call between managed and unmanaged code through callback

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management, unmanaged, managed

I have been facing a lot of issue in passing string between managed and unmanaged code. After searching and combining codes I have a solution which seems to work. But still I am not sure if it’s the correct implementation.

In my code c# passes a delegate function to c++. Now c++ calls that function whenever required. C++ needs to send string to call back function for which I am using BSTR. That’s how I implemented it.

C#

```
[DllImport("xyz.dll")]
public static extern void SetCallback(Callback fn);

public delegate void Callback([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]string str);
public Callback mInstance;

private void Handler(string text)
{
  NotifyListeners_uccx(text);
}

Private void setcallback(){
 mInstance = new Callback(Handler);
 SetCallback(mInstance);  }
```

C++

```
typedef void (__stdcall *Callback) (BSTR str);
Callback Handler;

extern "C" 
{   
      void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall SetCallback(Callback handler);
      void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall SendReceiveMessage(BSTR arr1); 
     }

 void __stdcall SendReceiveMessage(BSTR arr1) {
   Handler(arr1);
 }

void __stdcall SetCallback(Callback handler1) {
   Handler = handler1;
}

void CCall::sendmsg(FILE *fp)
{
//do some work
    try
{
    char *str;
    char *Tag_t;

    str = new char[2048];
    Tag_t = new char[1024];

    sprintf(str, "<body><Tag1>%d</Tag1 ><Tag2>%s</Tag2>",sumNum, SumString);

    for (int i = 0; i < sumNum; i++)
    {

        sprintf(Tag_t,"<Tag3>%s</Tag3>",tagString3,m_csqIDs[i],i);
        strcat(str,Tag_t);
    }
    strcat(str,"</body>");

    int wslen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str, strlen(str), 0, 0);
    BSTR bstr = SysAllocStringLen(0, wslen);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str, strlen(str), bstr, wslen);
    // Use bstr here
    SendReceiveMessage(bstr);
    SysFreeString(bstr);

    //SysFreeString(bstr);
    delete[] str;
    delete[] Tag_t;
}
catch(std::bad_alloc& exc)
{

    return;
}
  }
```

Please suggest if this is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You shouldn't call `SysFreeString(bstr);` twice, should you?

Comment: You are correct, i shouldn't. I commented out it from the code above.